# Drupal Webform. Embed nodes with a specific content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I want to create a form where the user can order some publications from a site, 
where the available publications is loaded/embedded automatic from the system (nodes with a specific content type).

I have created a Webform with some basic fields: Name, Email...

How do i add a field reference to these publications?

Like:

---

`Name` : `____________________________________`

`Email` : `___________________________________`

`Publications` :

`Publication 1`   Quantity `___`

`Publication 2`   Quantity `___`

---

Answer (score 1):

Your solution would be to add a webform component that acts as a node reference, perhaps [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/webform-and-node-reference) can help.